How to pack a file with some metainformation to 1-file-package
I have to put a file with some information (filename, content, time, sender, ...) in a one-file package. That package will processed elsewhere.
The content of the original file can be binary as well as text.
Normally I would put the information in the filename and keep the content of the file as it is - but I think it is too much for this requirement.
What's the best format/tech to do that?
I can think of XML, JSON, line-separated, keep the file and create an additional meta-file.
But maybe there is some better choice I did not think of for exactly that.
